# Update Twitter icon

Tags: feature-request, twitter

The logo/icon for sharing a post on Twitter is now outdated, since Twitter has upgraded their logo last week.

Could we get a fix on that?

Comment: Honestly, many of us like the old icon better, so we're in no hurry here...it's fairly time intensive to go through every theme and update these.

Comment: no way to do a merge on every one?

Comment: No, take a look at the themes, [RPG](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15027/as-a-gm-when-to-force-a-harrowed-player-for-control-of-his-body), [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151736/cannot-adjust-brightness-on-acer-aspire-5332), [Drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34276/how-to-call-default-node-validation-functions)...each theme has a different icon, often in a different sprite position, and needs a cache breaker update to boot.  It's a site-by-site very, *very* boring process that has to happen...changing these (*if* we do) will likely be with another update.

Comment: @NickCraver - thanks. i forgot about that...

Answer (score 4):

Just for reference, the new logo looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Im not entirely sure I understand this post. Is this some sort of meme?

Comment: Some people noticed that the new logo looks a bit like Batman when you turn it by 90 degrees, nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

[status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, the new logo looks like this:

[image]